# How to customize the title of the table of contents?

Tags: table-of-contents, tocloft

everybody.

I need to pass from this
[image]

to this
[image]

using this picture
[image]

This is my WME

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[spanish,english]{babel}
\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{fontspec}  

\setmainfont{georgia.TTF}[%Fuente para el cuerpo
Path=/usr/share/fonts/Win10/,
BoldItalicFont=georgiaz.TTF,
BoldFont      =georgiab.TTF,
ItalicFont    =georgiai.TTF]

\newfontfamily\myfont{calibri.TTF}[%Fuente para secciones
Path=/usr/share/fonts/Win10/,
BoldItalicFont=calibriz.TTF,
BoldFont      =calibrib.TTF,
ItalicFont    =calibrii.TTF]


\addto{\captionsspanish}{\renewcommand{\contentsname}{\color{myGris3} Contenido}}
\renewcommand{\cfttoctitlefont}{\Huge\bfseries\myfont}%Fuente para el título de la ToC
\renewcommand{\cftchapfont}{\Large\myfont}%Fuente para los capítulos
\renewcommand{\cftsecfont}{\myfont}%Fuente para las secciones
\renewcommand{\cftsubsecfont}{\myfont}%Fuente para las subsecciones

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\chapter{First Chapter}
\chapter{Second Chapter}
\appendix
\chapter{Appendix}

\end{document}
```

How could I do it?

Thanks for your help.

**EDIT:**  This is my MWE without TTF fonts.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[spanish,english]{babel}
\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}
\usepackage{tocloft}

\addto{\captionsspanish}{\renewcommand{\contentsname}{\color{myGris3} Contenido}}
\renewcommand{\cfttoctitlefont}{\Huge\bfseries\myfont}%Fuente para el título de la ToC
\renewcommand{\cftchapfont}{\Large\myfont}%Fuente para los capítulos
\renewcommand{\cftsecfont}{\myfont}%Fuente para las secciones
\renewcommand{\cftsubsecfont}{\myfont}%Fuente para las subsecciones

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\chapter{First Chapter}
\chapter{Second Chapter}
\appendix
\chapter{Appendix}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Why is this tagged `titletoc`, but you're not using it? You mean `tocloft`. And before asking new questions, consider first to upvote and accept answers to your questions in order to appreciate the help by the users here

Comment: I'm sorry.  Now I have corrected it.  The tag is tocloft.

Comment: Can you make a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) without exotic fonts so more people can try to help you?

Comment: What is the problem with the answer you already got?  https://i.stack.imgur.com/EO6PO.png https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/384107/36296

Comment: Hi, Sam Carter.  There is no problem with that answer.  Actually it worked very well, but ony for chapter headers.  Now I need to the same thing but with the title of the table of contents.  That answer doesn't work fot toc.

Comment: @Fabio As you can see in the image I linked in my previous comment, the other answer works very well for the table of contents. If it does not work for you, please make an example that shows the problems you experience.

Comment: @Fabio: Your reduced document still has the `\myfont` macro inside. Whatever `\myfont` is, your document does not compile for other ones

Comment: Hi, Sam.  You are right! That answer works very well for the table of contents.  I made a mistake because I forgot to set the "titles" option for the tocloft package. I wrote it and it worked perfectly!!! Thanks for your help.  Now, how could I close this topic if there is no answers? There is only comments.